# How to change MUI DataGrid footer's action buttons layout

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I created a data grid using MUI exact [demo code](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/) and noticed that the "Go to next/previous page" buttons in the footer are laid out vertically rather than horizontally as seen below: 

[image]

Any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is an MUI issue. My guess is that you are overriding all `button` styles in a global css file, causing the page navigation buttons in MUI DataGrid to be distorted.

Comment: You are right! I added more horizontal padding to all my buttons. Thanks a lot!